# Pass parameters to another page in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom, react-props

I'm having a problem where I want the information that is being passed on a page to be sent to another page, this other page I say is like a single page.

I've already tried to pass the parameters of this page to another with props, params, but without any success.

I believe it is something very simple, but it left me without a solution

Homepage.jsx

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import * as Styled from './styles';
import OwlCarousel from 'react-owl-carousel';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.css';
import 'owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.css';
import { FaStar,FaInfoCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import SinglePage from '../SinglePage';

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);  


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.rawg.io/api/games?key=328c7603ac77465895cf471fdbba8270')
     .then((res) => res.json())
     .then((data) => {
       setData(data.results);                  
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log(err);
     });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Styled.Container>                     
        <div className="boxSite">
          <div className="boxBrowse">
            <div className="boxAll">
              <OwlCarousel className='owl-theme' loop margin={0} items={6} center={true} dots= 
              {false}>                
                {data.map((games)=> (
                  <>
                    <div className="produto" key={games.id} layoutId={games.id}>
                      <div className="imagemGame" style={{backgroundImage: 
                    `url(${games.background_image})`}}>
                        <div className="information">                          
                          <NavLink to={{                            
                              pathname:`/single-game/${games.slug}`,                            
                            }}
                          >                          
                            <span>
                              <FaInfoCircle/>                            
                            </span>                          
                          </NavLink>    

                          <SinglePage name={games.name} />
                        </div>
                        <div className="classificacao">
                          <span> Avaliação <b> {games.rating} </b></span>
                          <span> <FaStar /></span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </>
                ))}                  
              </OwlCarousel>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
      </Styled.Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

SinglePage.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Styled from './styles';

export default function SinglePage(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>NAME OF THE GAME : {props.name}</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

Yes, I stopped here, please can someone help me?

Information is appearing on the Homepage, but not on the single page

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, if you're using version 5 or earlier of router-dom you can pass the data via state, using history:

Change this:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

return (
  <NavLink to={{                            
    pathname:`/single-game/${games.slug}`,                            
   }}>                          
    <span>
      <FaInfoCircle/>                            
    </span>                          
  </NavLink>
)
```

To this:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const history = useHistory();

return (
  <button
    onClick(() => history.push(`/single-game/${games.slug}`,{
      foo: 'bar',
      nameGame,
    }))
  >                          
    <span>
      <FaInfoCircle/>                            
    </span>                          
  </button>
)
```

And on your page you can get the data via props, like:

```
import React from 'react';

export default function SinglePage(props) {
  const { nameGame } = props.location.state;

  return (
    <>
     <h1>NAME OF THE GAME : {nameGame}</h1>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm using version 6, do you have any solution for this version? I tried using your answer but it didn't work for me.

I even edited the question, showing the result that was..

Comment: On version 6 you'll need to use 'navigation'

import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const navigate = useNavigate();

navigate('/other-page', { state: { foo: 'bar', nameGame } });

Comment: @FelipeGodoy Don't use a button and the `history` or `navigate` functions, just send the state via the link component you are already rendering.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your needs.

- If you need to access a lot of data over several pages, you should use a state management library like Redux.
- If it's only simple data, you can pass it as query parameters to your page.
- If it's a bit more complexe, you can use the session / local storage.

But it's a bit hard to know what to recommend you exactly without more info about what you want to achieve exactly.

Answer (score 0):

1. Import component into Homepage

```
import SinglePage from './your-single-page-file';
```

2. Use the tag and pass a parameter on the JSX

```
<SinglePage name={data.variableNeeded}  />
```

3. On the SinglePage function add the props parameter and use it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Styled from './styles';


 export default function SinglePage(props) {
 return (
    <>
     <h1>NAME OF THE GAME : {props.name}</h1>
   </>
 )
 }
```

Comment: I tried to do as you mentioned, but it didn't work.
I edited the question showing the result that appeared

Answer (score 0):

Since you only included the component that has a single `data` state that is mapped and renders some links I'll assume it is the `games` object you want to send to the linked route. Pass the data in route state via the `NavLink` component.

See [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/nav-link) and [Link](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/link)

> ```
> interface LinkProps
>   extends Omit<
>     React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>,
>     "href"
>   > {
>   replace?: boolean;
>   state?: any;
>   to: To;
>   reloadDocument?: boolean;
> }
> ```

Route state is sent along on the `state` prop of a link component.

Example:

```
{data.map((games) => (
  <div className="produto" key={games.id} layoutId={games.id}>
    <div
      ....
    >
      <div className="information">                          
        <NavLink
          to={`/single-game/${games.slug}`}
          state={{ games }} // <-- pass route state
        >                          
          <span>
            <FaInfoCircle/>                            
          </span>                          
        </NavLink>    

        <SinglePage name={games.name} />   
                            
      </div>
      ....
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

In the receiving component use the [`useLocation`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location) hook to access the passed route state.

Example:

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function SinglePage() {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { games } = state || {};

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <h1>NAME OF THE GAME : {games.name}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```